# Itunes Connect: Waiting for upload (application loader says: no eligible applications were found)

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

Application loader keeps telling me "no eligible applications were found" but I have submittet my App in itunes connect and it says "Waiting for upload"

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i  got it working now :D

It turns i needed Application Loader v. 1.4 to submit mac os apps. To get it you need to either re/install xcode or update to xcode v. 4 GM seed.

Answer (score 0):

If the answer above me doesn't work, you can also click the blue button at the top right of your app's page in ITC and then click on "Continue" in the top right corner.